# Safari extension background script by default not allowed to access sites in SFSafariWebsiteAccess in Info.plist

Tags: safari-extension

I'm developing a Safari extension and need the background script to be able to use the `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` API when certain pages are loaded (let's say, `example.com` pages).

I have this in my `manifest.json`:

```
...
"permissions":["*://*.example.com/*"]
...
```

And I have this in the `Info.plist` for the extension target in my macOS app:

```
...
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.Safari.web-extension</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SafariWebExtensionHandler</string>
        <key>SFSafariWebsiteAccess</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Level</key>
            <string>Some</string>
            <key>Allowed Domains</key>
            <array>
                <string>example.com</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
...
```

The extension is working except that the extension does not by default have access to `example.com` pages. When I build the extension in Xcode and load it in Safari, then go to `Safari > Preferences > Extensions > My Extension > Edit Websites`, `example.com` is listed under "Configured Websites", but with the `Ask` option selected. If I update it to `Allow`, the extension works as expected.

How can I configure the app such that the extension automatically has access to `example.com` pages when the user activates it? I've seen other extensions that have access to webpages automatically, but I don't know how they do it.

Many, many thanks for your help!

Documents reviewed:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/safari_app_extension_info_property_list_keys/adjusting_website_access_permissions
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/managing_safari_web_extension_permissions

Answer (score 1):

It appears that that's the default and can't be changed. Safari simply handles the hosts in `permissions` as *suggested websites* rather than *pre-approved websites*. The user has to manually enable each website in the options or via the "browser action" button.